# TypeError: UserMixin.get_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' - Flask Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm new to flask login and trying to work out how it all works, Im sure its an easy fix but can't seem to see it anywhere.

I have built a USER model to start with and then added flask login after the event and I have the error TypeError: UserMixin.get_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when I try and log in.

So i have the following in my app.py

```py
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.login_message_category = "info"

from models.users import User


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

and then ion my user model I have the following:

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(16))
    last_name = Column(String(16))
    phone = Column(String(16))
    email = Column(String(32), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(128))
```

And the my login function looks like so

```py
@app.route('/cms-login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        test = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if test:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(test.password, password):
                login_user(User)
                return redirect(url_for('blogs_blueprint.home'))
            else:
                error = 'Password is incorrect. Please try again'
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: Instead of passing User in login_user(User), consider passing test to login_user(test).